# Less than or equal set to a given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, soft-question

Suppose that $M$ is a given positive definite $n\times n$ real matrix. I'm interested in the following sets and their properties
\begin{align*}
S_1&\equiv\{N\text{ positive semidefinite, dimension }n\times n: M-N\text{ is positive semidefinite}\}\subset \mathbb{M}(n),\\
S_2&\equiv\{x\text{ dimension }n\times1: M-xx'\text{ is positive semidefinite}\}\subset\mathbb{R}^n.
\end{align*}
The problem collapses to triviality when $n=1$ but harder for me to grasp when $n\geq 2$. I will appreciate references to books and articles, with a preference for the former.

Comment: The book “Problems and Theorems of Linear Algebra” by Prasolov may be relevant

Comment: @Selflearner Thank you. I will check it out tonight.